# Visual studio 2017 slow when generating ipa for publishing ios apple store

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

My visual studio at the time I build it takes a long time to finish the process, it takes almost 50 min to finish the process, at times when it seems to really crash, this only in my ios xamarin project. To some configuration to make to go faster. I have to generate my IPA for publication in the Apple store even though I give ZIP app Bundle stay well slow. What can this be ?

Comment: Turn on Msbuild diagnostic level logging and you will receive a breakdown of the time spent in the major steps to determine where the time is being spent.

Comment: Any log did you collect? Merely saying something is slow won't lead to any serious discussion.